# Picasso url does not load

Tags: android, picasso

I have a dynamic url to show avatars for users.

http://www.dapptapp.com/contents/avatar/200/200/27.png

the image does show in the browser but picasso does not show any image.

the current code is used:

```
 getPicasso().load("http://www.dapptapp.com/contents/avatar/200/200/27.png").into(civAvatar);
```

is it something that has to do with the headers of the image or something. I can't seem to pinpoint the error. If I use any other regular image from the web there is no problem.

Postman response on the URL:

```
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding →
Content-Encoding
The type of encoding used on the data.

gzip
Content-Length →36908
Content-Type →image/png
Date →Tue, 03 Jun 2014 14:44:22 GMT
Keep-Alive →timeout=1, max=100
Server →Apache
Vary →Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

Comment: You mean to say other image urls are working, only this url is not working?

Comment: @Toby I will need to investigate this.

Comment: Looks like a 504 Gateway timeout is thrown for this url.

Comment: @Toby The server returns the response with 0 content-length. I think thats the problem.

Comment: But my postman says the following. I have made en edit with postman response.

Comment: @Toby `curl -I http://www.dapptapp.com/contents/avatar/200/200/27.png` does not show the `content-length` header.

Comment: So the trick would be to set this header programmaticly in the php script?

Comment: Yes, possibly. But I am fixing it for Picasso.

Comment: Made sure that the header contains a content-length but this still does not work...

Comment: @Toby can you try 2.3.2? Its going live now so it might be a few hours before its available on maven central.

Answer (score 1):

I was run into this problem too.

If ok-http lib not provided, Picasso using UrlConnectionDownloader to load url.

Seems that some times it load url with param boolean localCacheOnly=true, and a header is setting to HttpUrlConnection.

```
connection.setUseCaches(true)
connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached,max-age=" + Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Then it returns this header:

```
X-Android-Response-Source CACHE 504
```

Fixed by fork Picasso and comment these lines. I thinks there may be better solutions.